# is there any proverb for "being insanity is better than suicide"

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

when people do not have any option to do then they go for worst option even person knows that it hurts him or it is not the solution even to escape from that problem... than we have one proverb which literally means that "being insanity is better than doing suicide" 
is there any proverb which has similar meaning

Comment: *Life is better than nothing*.

Comment: *Anything is better than death*.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There+is+a+remedy+for+everything+except+death

Answer (score 1):

One common quotation is "Where there's life, there's hope". However, a fuller quote (NIV bible) might be

> Anyone who is among the living has hope<sup>[[a](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes+9%3A4&version=NIV#fen-NIV-17480a)]</sup>—even a live dog is better off than a dead lion!
>
> [Ecclesiastes 9:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes+9%3A4&version=NIV).